# Can I use meteor.js just for back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mobile, meteor-blaze

I have to build a mobile app that's needs a high level of reactivity. I thought to use meteor.js just for my back end and build the app using native technologies. Can this work?

Comment: Meteor is a complete platform for building web and mobile apps in pure JavaScript. What's your idea to use both of native and  a JavaScript platform?

Comment: my idea is to use meteor as service app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can, but you need to evaluate how reliable it will be.

If you're thinking about using JavaScript to write your native app (e.g. React Native) then you have good NPM packages that can help you with this task. For example:
https://blog.meteor.com/leverage-the-power-of-meteor-with-any-client-side-framework-bfb909141008

But if you're thinking about writing completely native code for iOS and Android and still have a DDP connection to use everything from Meteor you'll need to find a third part library written for your platform.
I've tried this in the past and had a bad experience. Once Meteor started getting updates the library broke and my app would not work anymore. This means you would need to find a well maintained project that is always up to date.

I hope I could help a little. It's not a simple decision, but if you research hard enough you can find out what's the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I advice you give it up if you wanna an app with high reactivity and high performance.